# Converted an Object with keys from multiple array for sorting and now want them back as arrays as they are in sorted

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
var values =selectValues;
    var names = selectNames;
    var priorities = prioritizedHours;
    var prefers = preferHrsArray;
    var years = workedYearsArray;
    var items = values.map((value, index) => {
                           return {
                           value: value,
                           name: names[index],
                           priority: priorities[index],
                           prefer: prefers[index],
                           year: years[index]
                           }
                           });
    var arrayObject = JSON.stringify(items);
    Logger.log('Object array: '+arrayObject);
```

In the above program, I am creating an object from the arrays such as names, priorities, and so on. Resulting Object is following after I have made a sorting of them:

```js
[
  {"value":1,"name":"Fiona","prefer":30,"year":6},
  {"value":1,"name":"Martin","prefer":40,"year":7},
  {"value":2,"name":"Adam","prefer":0,"year":20},
  {"value":2,"name":"Steve","prefer":100,"year":5}
]
```

Now as sorting is done, I want the arrays back as they are in the Object.
I am trying to get arrays like:

```js
value = [1,1,2,2],
name = ['Fiona', 'Martin','Adam', 'Steve'],
prefer = [30,40,0,100],
year = [6,7,20,5]
```

Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A `for` loop with `Array.prototype.push()` should do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use forEach for this case

```js
const array = [
  {"value":1,"name":"Fiona","prefer":30,"year":6},            
  {"value":1,"name":"Martin","prefer":40,"year":7},
  {"value":2,"name":"Adam","prefer":0,"year":20},
  {"value":2,"name":"Steve","prefer":100,"year":5}
]

const values = []
const names = []
const prefers = []
const years = []

array.forEach(rec => {
  values.push(rec.value),
  names.push(rec.name),
  prefers.push(rec.prefer),
  years.push(rec.year)
})

console.log(values)
console.log(names)
console.log(prefers)
console.log(years)
```

Comment: This is what I did, except that I had to use   var sortedObj = JSON.stringify(items); for object.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 3):

Map should work:

```
    const data = [
      { value: 1, name: "Fiona", prefer: 30, year: 6 },
      { value: 1, name: "Martin", prefer: 40, year: 7 },
      { value: 2, name: "Adam", prefer: 0, year: 20 },
      { value: 2, name: "Steve", prefer: 100, year: 5 },
    ];
    
    const values = data.map(x=>x.value);
    const names = data.map(x=>x.name);
    
    console.log(values, names);
    //[ 1, 1, 2, 2 ] [ 'Fiona', 'Martin', 'Adam', 'Steve' ]
```

See [MDN for details of map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 2):

You could also make it a little more dynamic by using reduce and then only getting the lists you want using [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const arr = [
  {"value":1,"name":"Fiona","prefer":30,"year":6},
  {"value":1,"name":"Martin","prefer":40,"year":7},
  {"value":2,"name":"Adam","prefer":0,"year":20},
  {"value":2,"name":"Steve","prefer":100,"year":5}
];

const {name, value, prefer, year} = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  Object.entries(curr).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    if(acc[key] == null) 
      acc[key] = [];
     
    acc[key].push(val);
  });
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(name);
console.log(value);
console.log(prefer);
console.log(year);
```

Comment: You know that there are 4 properties (`const {name, value, prefer, year} = ... `) but in the `.reduce()` call you act like you don't know them anymore. Why?

Comment: Because in the `reduce()` I don't care what properties exist. There could be 1000 properties in each element - I just add them all up into one big object, so that I can later pick the ones I need. I tried to make a more generalized approach, because the given example in OPs question is just an example and it could potentially be a lot more properties. @Andreas